# How to prevent from entering future date angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, mean

i wanna add inline validation to prevent user from entering future date 
like if i add 2022 i should give me an error like you add wrong date or something

**this is my html code**

```
<div class="form-group datepicker">
      <label for="dob">Date of Birth*</label>
      <div class="row input-group">
        <input
          ngbDatepicker
          #d="ngbDatepicker"
          #dobF="ngModel"
          class="form-control input-underline input-lg"
          id="dob"
          [(ngModel)]="dateOfBirth"
          placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
          name="dp"
          [ngClass]="{
            invalid:
              (dobF.value === null || isString(dobF.value)) && dobF.touched
          }"
          required
        />
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button
            class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar"
            (click)="d.toggle()"
            type="button"
          ></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        *ngIf="
          (dobF.value === null || isString(dobF.value)) && dobF.touched
        "
        class="error"
      >
        Please enter a valid date of birth.
      </div>
    </div>
```

**this is my Ts file**

where i defined dateOfBirth

```
public dateOfBirth: { year: number; month: number; day: number };
 constructor(
public router: Router,
public route: ActivatedRoute,
private modalService: NgbModal,
private store: Store<any>,
private authService: AuthService,
public config: NgbDatepickerConfig,
private duplicateFinderService: DuplicateFinderService
) 
{
const currentDate = new Date();
const day = currentDate.getDate();
const month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
const year = currentDate.getFullYear();
// customize default values of datepickers used by this component tree
this.config.minDate = { year: 1900, month: 1, day: 1 };
this.config.maxDate = { year, month, day };
// days that don't belong to current month are not visible
this.config.outsideDays = "hidden";
}
```

i cant seem to find any help on the internet.
can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: What version of ng-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I can see `maxDate` option here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api

Comment: @ChrisTapay 1.0.0-alpha.26

Comment: Thanks @UsmanSaleem. I just put an answer, we can go further from that.

Comment: @PrerakSola i tried to add it but it did not work

Comment: Could you please add the code in which you added it?

Comment: tried it in html like max = {{maxDate}} but did not help

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using a ngbDatepicker, one option is to set the `maxDate` attribute and add the `readonly` attribute too. That way, the users will be forced to use the datepicker and do not type directly anything else into the input field.

`[maxDate]="maxDate" readonly`

Comment: requirement is user can add manual date too but when add future it should give an error.
right now it does not give anything

Comment: Then, I recommend to use Reactive Forms and define a custom validator.

Comment: is there any other way without reactive form? @Chris Tapay

Comment: Yes, you may try using a regular expression to match your date format, and then parse it as Date object (you can use momentjs for that) and finally, compare with the actual date to make sure if not higher than that.

Comment: how exactly? i tried that but did not work either @Chris Tapay